# jQuery: Temporarily toggleClass / addClass, removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zeroclipboard

I'm using the following code with [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) to change the `innerHTML` text and class of my 'copy to clipboard button'. Once clicked, this animates the class transition.

```
client.on( "complete", function(client, args) {
            this.innerHTML = 'Copied to Clipboard';
            $( this ).removeClass( "btn-info" ).addClass( "btn-success", 357 );         
            });
```

Is there a way in which I could make this change of class and innerHTML temporary? i.e. change the class (to `btn-success`) for only a few seconds to indicate that the button was clicked, and auto revert back to it's original class (`btn-info`)? And remove the added `innerHTML = 'Copied to Clipboard'`

So the class transition would be '`btn-info`' > '`btn-success`' > '`btn-info`'. And revert the `innerHTML` back to whatever it was beforehand (each button has different innerHTML).

I've tried experimenting with toggleClass, but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a simple timeout

```
client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
    var html = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = 'Copied to Clipboard';
    var $this = $(this).removeClass("btn-info").addClass("btn-success");

    //clear previous timer
    clearTimeout($this.data('completeToggler'))
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.addClass("btn-info").removeClass("btn-success");
        $this.html(html)
    }, 2000);
    $this.data('completeToggler', timer);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/969VK/)

---

also try using toggleClass()

```
client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
    this.innerHTML = 'Copied to Clipboard';
    var $this = $(this).toggleClass("btn-info btn-success");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.toggleClass("btn-info btn-success");
    }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Both work great. I did forget to ask how I could remove the innerHTML added? I not sure how I could revert that, as the HTML is different for each button. Will update my question.

Comment: Thanks again. However, the timeout solution doesn't seem to be working. The added button class and innerHTML remain.?

Comment: @ElijahPaul made a mess.. some mistakes used `timer` instead of `$this`

Comment: @ElijahPaul see the fiddle

Comment: Works perfectly. Never thought of using `setTimeout`. Thanks again.